# Force type on Doctrine2 @JoinColumn annotation without using ColumnDefinition

Tags: symfony, join, orm, types, doctrine

I have a legacy database which must be maintained exactly as is in terms of data types, column names and sizes etc. With an extra Column annotation the relations are rendered useless. With columnDefinition like this:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_contact", referencedColumnName="contact_id", nullable=false, columnDefinition="int(11) DEFAULT '0'")
```

the change script always runs, so it is not a good solution. Is there any way to specify the type, length (size) and default value of a JoinColumn?

Answer (score -3):

**JoinColumn** annotation is used in the process of creating relationships between entities not for creating new columns. From the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn),

> This annotation is used in the context of relations in @ManyToOne,
> @OneToOne fields and in the Context of @JoinTable nested inside a
> @ManyToMany.

A new column is created using **column** annotation. Look at this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_contact", type="integer", options={"default":0})
 */
private $userContact;
```

**Update**
Latest documentation on columns and join columns annotation reference can be found here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/annotations-reference.html